# JQuery-mobile panel enables horizontal scrolling

Tags: ios, jquery-mobile, cordova

When using JQuery-mobile with phonegap on iOS, I had a panel open, but then the horizontal scrolling is enabled, causing trouble for me, so I can scroll entire page together with panel to the left. how to disable horizontal scrolling when panel is open?

Comment: Try this css fix. `.ui-panel { overflow: hidden; }` and `.ui-panel-inner { overflow-y: scroll; }`. Plus make sure the height of the panel isn't greater than the page's height.

Comment: Check this demo, create a panel and then add contents as much as you want. The inner div will scroll leaving page still. http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/a2PVU/

Comment: Unfortunate this does not work. I can still scroll the entire page to the left.

Comment: Oops, my bad, this fixes vertical scroll. Ui-page should have overflow-x hidden when the panel is open. Try `.ui-page-active.ui-page-panel { overflow-x: hidden }`

Comment: Thank you very much. Sometime its really difficult to know all css stuff. maybe need to start reading some good css book.

Comment: so `.ui-page-active.ui-page-panel { overflow-x: hidden }` fixed it?

Comment: yes, although the panel itself can still be scrolled, but the page is not scrollable

Answer (score 0):

I just came across the same problem with phonegap and android. 
What fixed it for me was getting rid of data-display="overlay" or display="push". Even though it doesn't slide in anymore the menu still works. 
Hope this can help.

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery Mobile 1.4.5, the version with which I encountered this issue, the cause is that the `html` element allows horizontal scrolling. This can be fixed by setting either

```
html { overflow-x: hidden; }
```

or

```
.ui-mobile { overflow-x: hidden }
```